# Javascripts in jMeter response of SPA

Tags: jmeter

I am doing automation using API testing for mobile app.
There are 3 different home screens on app.
Workflow-
1)Login- Sending login API request & in response getting access token which is used in further requests.
2) Screen1-Sending API request on screen1 & getting response -Success
3) Screen2 -sending API request on screen2 & but its not working .**It sends 3-4 .js(javascripts) files in response. Screen2 is Single page application. Jmeter does not execute those js from response hence no content seen.**

I am blocked here & cant proceed .Any pointer ...appreciated.

Comment: Similarly tried with Soap UI ,it doesnot execute javascript from response.Same response.
any tool offering js executor?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all check whether JMeter is configured to download embedded resources. You can do it on "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults))

   [image: JMeter HTTP Request Defaults]

   If this box is unchecked - JMeter will return only main content but will not process any so called "embedded resources": images, fonts, **scripts**, styles which are referenced by the webpage.
2. As per [JMeter project main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

   > JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does

   So if there is a JavaScript somewhere in the response which triggers an [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) request which returns your "js" files - JMeter won't execute it automatically, you will need to add a separate HTTP Request sampler(s) to mimic the AJAX call(s)

---

None of the load testing tools is capable of executing JavaScript so if you looking for a one - you need to consider real browsers. For example check out JMeter integration with [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) via [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/), but be aware that this approach is very resource intensive.

Comment: Thanks for reply..it's useful.   1) download resources does not help as it just shows JavaScripts code in response ,earlier it was showing filename.js.    2) I have added webdriver sampler but I am not getting how it will execute java script from my earlier response.    Can you please advice how I can achieve this?   I am sending first login request and then request to another page using access token user specific .  Would like to discuss with you if you are available.